# How to Update Test Results in Azure DevOps with Python REST API?

Tags: python, azure-devops-rest-api

How to UpdateTest Results in Azure DevOps with Python REST API?
I have connected azure rest api using vsts python library, I can able to retrive test run results or test runs, but i am not able to update test case result. kindly help if any one have knowledge in this part.

connected module for test retrive test run vsts.core.v4_1.core_client.TestClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connected module should be **vsts.test.v4_1.test_client.TestClient** not  `vsts.core.v4_1.core_client.TestClient`

If we want to update the test results, we could use the `test_client.update_test_results()` method in the test_client.
For more information, please refer to [Azure Devops Python Rest API source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/vsts/vsts/test/v4_1/test_client.py#L1225).

```
personal_access_token = 'xxx'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}'
# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = VssConnection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
test_client = connection.get_client('vsts.test.v4_1.test_client.TestClient')
update_testResults = test_client.update_test_results(testresults,projectName,run.id)
```